# Grouping by date range combined with another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I have something like the following:

```
Create table #RateHistory (RatePlan char(1), EventDate datetime)

Insert into #RateHistory  (RatePlan, EventDate)
VALUES 
('a','10/01/2013')  
,('a','10/04/2013') 
,('a','10/06/2013') 
,('a','10/08/2013') 
,('b','10/21/2013') 
,('b','11/05/2013') 
,('b','11/12/2013') 
,('b','12/05/2013') 
,('a','12/08/2013') 
,('a','12/09/2013') 
,('a','12/10/2013') 
,('a','12/15/2013')
```

I'd like to see an output like this:

```
Rateplan MinDate     MaxDate
-------- ----------- -----------
a        2013-10-01  2013-10-08 
b        2013-10-21  2013-12-05 
a        2013-12-08  2013-12-15
```

(originally this was a bit different, but I believe this result set makes it clearer what I actually need, which is the correct grouping)

Note that RatePlan "a" shows up twice, and that I want it to be grouped separately - once for the 10/1/2013 to 10/8/2013 data, and once for the 12/8/2013 to 12/15/2013 data.  I've got the solution I need with this :

```
-- Get initial row numbers
;with Test as (
    Select 
    *
    ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EventDate) 
    from #RateHistory            
)
-- Get initial row numbers
, Test2 as (
SelecT 
    Main.RowNumber
    ,Main.EventDate
    ,Main.RatePlan
    ,FollowingRatePlan = Following.RatePlan
    ,NewGroup = 
        case
            when Main.RatePlan <> Following.RatePlan  
                -- if Following RatePlan is null, that means this is the last record
                or (Following.RatePlan is  null ) 
            then Main.EventDate
            else null
        end
from Test Main 
    left join Test following 
        on Following.RowNumber = Main.RowNumber + 1
)      
, Test3 as (
select 
    #RateHistory.RatePlan
    ,#RateHistory.EventDate
    ,MaxDate = min(Test2.NewGroup)
from #RateHistory  
    join Test2 
        on #RateHistory .RatePlan  = Test2.RatePlan
        and #RateHistory .EventDate <= Test2.NewGroup
where Test2.NewGroup is not null    
group by 
    #RateHistory.RatePlan
    ,#RateHistory.EventDate

)
select Rateplan, MinDate = MIN(EventDate) , MaxDate 
from Test3 
group by RatePlan,MaxDate
```

...but I'm thinking - there's GOT to be a better, more elegant way of doing this.  Thoughts?  If nobody has anything better, I'll just go ahead and put this in as an answer...

Thanks!

Comment: Just looking at your required output, `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MONTH(EventDate) ASC, YEAR(EventDate) ASC, RatePlan)` should get you that result.

Comment: Sorry - I'll update the test data - it's just random that they happened to split by month.

Comment: Also a more precise description of how you want them grouped and ranked would be more helpful.

Comment: done - hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a solution using correlated scalar sub-queries. You tell me if it's more elegant. Or better performing.

```
select distinct
  rh0.RatePlan,
  (
    select min(EventDate) 
    from RateHistory rh1 
    where rh1.RatePlan = rh0.RatePlan 
    and rh1.EventDate <= rh0.EventDate
    and not exists 
    (
      select * from RateHistory rh2
      where rh2.RatePlan != rh0.RatePlan
      and rh2.EventDate > rh1.EventDate
      and rh2.EventDate < rh0.EventDate
    )
  ) as mindate,
  (
    select max(EventDate) 
    from RateHistory rh1 
    where rh1.RatePlan = rh0.RatePlan 
    and rh1.EventDate >= rh0.EventDate
    and not exists 
    (
      select * from RateHistory rh2
      where rh2.RatePlan != rh0.RatePlan
      and rh2.EventDate < rh1.EventDate
      and rh2.EventDate > rh0.EventDate
    )
  ) as maxdate
from RateHistory rh0
order by mindate
```

[Check out the SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62130/7/1). BTW 2012 has some cool features that could make your version of the query more elegant.